# Error with ajax cart when add product to cart, prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, compiler-errors, prestashop

I've seen similar question here, but that was a long time ago and there was no any exact solving issue. So here is my question:
I'm using standard prestashop cart module and when i'm adding a product to the cart i got an error in console

```
ajax-cart.js:323 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of null
at Object.success (ajax-cart.js:323)
at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

After page reloading cart updates and we see a product there.
The same happens when i'm trying to remove a product from cart, but for this time i have another error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of null
at Object.updateCart (ajax-cart.js:738)
at Object.success (ajax-cart.js:402)
at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

And again after page reloading everything is updated and product removed from cart. 
The thing is that we're receiving null in jsonData and that is why we can't check it for ther errors, it seems to be a problem on the backend. In the previous topics there were something about SmartyPlugin that can be a cause of this issue. But even after manual cash cleaning and disabling this plugin this errors still there.

Here is the link to the page with this issue:

[cart adding issue](http://phpstack-99322-293112.cloudwaysapps.com/prestashop/en/ao/1-product.html)

Is there anybody who had a deal with something like that?
Any ideas?

Will be very glad to any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. In the end the problem was in __DIR__override/controllers/front/CartController.php

wrong path were written in the end of the file

```
        elseif (file_exists(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/ohmcart/ohmcart-ajax.php'))
        require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/ohmcart/ohmcart-ajax.php');
```

instead of ohmcart must be blockcart path